# How to use a div to style radio buttons with javascript

Tags: javascript, radio-button, label

I am trying to make radio buttons appear one under the other, each with their labels. 
I have used a loop which goes through contents of a json file and creates radio buttons with their labels next to them successfully, but they appear next to each other instead:
[image]

I have attempted to wrap the radio buttons and the labels in a div so that they appear one under the other, but i am not sure how to do it. This is what i have so far:

```
for (const o of i.options){

        const x = document.createElement("INPUT");
        x.setAttribute("type", "radio");
        x.setAttribute("id", "lord");
        window.data.appendChild(x);


        const y = document.createElement("LABEL");
        const t = document.createTextNode(o);
        y.textContent = "Label text";
        y.setAttribute("for", "lord");
        window.data.appendChild(t);

        const div = document.createElement("div");
        div.style.width = "200px";
        div.style.height = "5px";
        document.getElementById("radioButton1").appendChild(div);
      }
```

Comment: use css float / clear

Comment: Thank you, I will check to see if I can get it working with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of appending the `radio` and `label` to window, append them to the `div` then append the `div` to the parent element.

Since `div` is block level element, it should come vertically

```
for (const o of i.options) {

  const x = document.createElement("INPUT");
  x.setAttribute("type", "radio");
  x.setAttribute(o.id, "lord"); // if there is id key available 


  const y = document.createElement("LABEL");
  const t = document.createTextNode(o);
  y.appendChild(t); // cheanged here
  y.setAttribute("for", "lord");


  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.style.width = "200px";
  div.style.height = "5px";
  div.appendChild(x); //changed here
  div.appendChild(y); //changed here
  document.getElementById("radioButton1").appendChild(div);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I have tried it and it works. I am wondering if there is a better way to style it instead of using the width and the height?

Comment: This will create multiple inputs with the same ID. That's invalid.